# Import Activity Issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, import, data-import

I am facing a very weired issue with my import activity. My client drops a file on FTP everyday with more than 100k records on daily basis. The import was working fine, until since few days it has stopped working. Every time a file is dropped I get the below notification from the Import notification.

*The following import has completed with validation errors 05 May 2020 13:28:00 GMT+0
    Name: IS:5-4F76-9A46-6C236000A4DB_35126479920
    External Key: 5-4F76-9A46-6C236000A4DB_35126479920
    Source: file.csv
    Destination: DENAME
Results:
    Inserted: 40000
    Updated: 0
ValidationErrors:
    Field Not Found: 1
Validation results have been logged to a delimited text file and attached to this message.
MID 000000*

When I manually look in the file, I do not see any issue, all the required fields have values, and there is absolutely no issue data wise.

The interesting part is the import activity only inserts 40k records. The target DE has more 30 million records.
When I try to load the file in a test DE with an overwrite data notification, it works fine , but when I try to do and add or update it fails with above error.

Has someone faced this issue? Also, can someone tell me how can I look that the file has some kind of illegal character or something, it does not show anything when file is opened using notepad or excel.

Below is the import activity setup.
[image]

Comment: What's the error being shown for each of the rows in the error file?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The issue was figured out, actually there a few columns in my DE which are nullable. The import activity has a setting, the files includes header. Now, although the fields are nullable, if the import file does not contain headers for all the DE fields, the activity gives a Field not found error, even though all the required fields are present. Seems weird, but if the import file is modified to include headers for all the fields of DE, then the import works fine.